# I have an open source puppet master and agent installed. How to install a software?

Tags: puppet

How to install a software using open source puppet? Please provide example. Kindly give one example with Windows as Agent and Linux as Agent

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you can install puppet modules.

[Puppet documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_installing.html) can guide you to install them.

However, it must depend on the way you have configured Puppet because you can install the modules in the puppet directory or have git repositories to take them.
The easiest one is install puppet modules from [puppet forge](https://forge.puppet.com/).

Please, give more information in order to help you.

Comment: I have Puppet Master installed in RHEL7. I will be installing Puppet Agent in Windows and Linux systems. If I have to install Adobe PDF Reader in both the agents, please let me know the steps.

Comment: Have you properly configured the Puppet Master and Puppet Agent? Are the agents certificates signed and the Master can establish connections with them?

Comment: Yes David .They are all done. Please let me know any sample software to be installed.

Comment: if you have properly configured the puppet repositories in your master, you can execute on it, for example: `sudo puppet module install puppetlabs-apache` and then, call it in your site.pp like this `'nodename.domain.org' {
include module_class
}`. After that, execute puppet agent

Comment: Okay David M. I am able to run a simple "Hello World" program from Puppet Master as well as from agent. They both are communicating now. I will try this!